# EDI 820 - Can the monetary amount be negative?

Tags: edi

I've looked through a few different EDI 820 specs online and have not seen any guidance as to how to handle the monetary amount (BPR.02) when the Credit/Debit Flag Code (BPR.03) is "D". If the code is D, should the amount be negative or positive? Is the amount allowed to be negative at all, per the spec?

I searched through my company's internal EDI spec, as well as a few online versions. None mentioned how to handle the amount when the Credit/Debit Flag Code is D, and none that I looked at even showed an example of a transaction in which BPR.03 was "D".

Comment: It should be positive. You don't issue refunds for negative dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X12 usually specifies or explains when a number can be negative in the syntax notes. For example, let's look at the `ADX` (Adjustment) segment (https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12-008010/segment/ADX).

> ADX01 specifies the amount of the adjustment and must be signed if negative. If negative, it reduces the payment amount; if positive, it increases the payment amount.

However, it looks like the `BPR` segment (https://www.stedi.com/edi/x12/segment/BPR) doesn't have any syntax notes for the `02` / `03` elements.

I'd expect the number to be positive following the debit or credit qualifier code in the `BPR-03`.

Credit = payment

Debit = refund

Technically, a negative debit could be a credit, but I don't see the benefit of expressing it that way given the presence of the flag.

Answer (score 0):

D is an interesting case. 820 is issued by a payer, either as an instruction to a financial institution to transfer funds, or to the payee to inform them of a future transfer of funds. The only time you would use D is when you are instructing the payee that you (as a payer) will be removing funds from their account. This isn’t common, likely because in an ongoing trade relationship there is usually a one-way flow of funds, and any credits or discounts will only be reflected in a smaller future transfer, and not an outright reversal. In multiple trading documents I’ve seen, any reversal of funds flow happens outside of EDI. The one exception may be Ford Motor Co., though I do not have first hand knowledge.

It might not be surprising then that the HIPAA 820 only allows for C - Credit.

Are you asking out of pure curiosity, or do you think you will need to handle this situation? You should not need to handle D unless you have an implementation guide from a trading partner indicating that they will use it. In which case you should give them a call.